# Thomae's function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

I am self-learning `Real Analysis` from Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis. I'd like to ask, if my below proof is technically correct and rigorous.

> Problem 4.2.3. Consider the Thomae's function $t(x)$ defined as follows:

\begin{align*}
t(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x = 0\\
\frac{1}{n} & \text { if } x = \frac{m}{n} \in \mathbf{Q}\setminus \{0\}\\
0 & \text { if } x \notin \mathbf{Q}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

> (a) Construct three different sequences $(x_n)$, $(y_n)$ and $(z_n)$ each of which converges to $1$ without using the number $1$ as a term in the sequence.

> (b) Now, compute $\lim t(x_n)$, $\lim t(y_n)$ and $\lim t(z_n)$.

> (c) Make an educated conjecture for $\lim_{x \to 1} t(x)$ and use the definition of functional limits to verify the claim. Given $\epsilon > 0$, consider the set of points $\{x \in \mathbf{R}, t(x)\ge \epsilon\}$. Argue that all the points in this set are isolated.

***Proof.***

Consider $x_n:= \frac{n}{n+1}$. The first few terms of the sequence are,

\begin{align*}
(x_n) = \frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{4},\frac{4}{5},\ldots
\end{align*}

Consider $y_n:= 1$.

The first few terms of the sequence are,

\begin{align*}
(y_n) = 1,1,1,1,1, \ldots
\end{align*}

Consider $(z_n):= \frac{n+\sqrt{2}}{n}$.

The first few terms of the sequence are,

\begin{align*}
(z_n) = \frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{1}, \frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}, \frac{3+\sqrt{2}}{3}, \frac{4+\sqrt{2}}{4}, \ldots
\end{align*}

(b) The corresponding image sequences are:

\begin{align*}
t(x_n) &= \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},\ldots\\
t(y_n) &= 1,1,1,1,\ldots\\
t(z_n) &= 0,0,0,0,\ldots
\end{align*}

Thus, $\lim_{x_n \to 1}t(x_n) = \lim_{z_n \to 1}t(z_n) \ne 1 = t(1)$

(c) We conjecture that $\lim_{x \to 1} t(x)$ does not exist. Clearly, from the sequential characterization of functional limits, for all sequences $(x_n)$ in the domain of $t$, whenever $(x_n) \to 1$ and $x_n \ne 1$, we have $t(x_n) \to L$, then $\lim_{x_n \to 1}t(x_n) = L$.

Clearly, this condition is not satisfied. $\lim_{x \to 1}t(x)$ is not well-defined.

Comment: The question asks you to come up with sequences that *don't* use the number $1$ as a term, so the sequence $(y_n)$ should be made into something different. It might affect your conjecture too.

Comment: +1 for writing a good question with all the relevant context. Exercises on Thomae function are famous and you should search for it on this site.

Comment: I conjecture that $\lim_{x \to 1} t(x) = 0$. If I were to disprove this, we must show that given any $\epsilon > 0$, there is atleast one sequence $(x_n) \to 1$ such that $\vert {t(x_n)} \vert \ge \epsilon$. Consider the set $\{x \in \mathbf{R}:t(x) \ge \epsilon\}$.

How do I complete the proof of (c)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the definition of limit you take. If you consider \begin{equation} \lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L \iff \forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists \delta > 0 : 0 < \vert x\vert < \delta \Rightarrow \vert f(x) \vert < L \end{equation}
then the limit exists and its value is $0$ as you can conjecture from the sequences $(x_{n})$ and $(z_{n})$ you have defined. Indeed, exercise $(a)$ tells you that you cannot consider $1$ as a term in the sequences so $(y_{n})$ is not properly defined according to the exercise. Define another sequence $(y_{n})$ without using $1$ as a term and you will get $f(y_{n}) \to 0$

Comment: That was a clear oversight on my part. Precisely why $t(x)$ is not continuous at $x=1$.